# paypal return field ignored on live

Tags: paypal

I have a form like the below which works correctly when the business is a sandbox account but not when I use a genuine business account.
In the latter scenario the return field is never shown and instead I am seeing a paypal payment confirmation page.
I've tried enabling/disabling auto-return in the business account but it makes no difference.. any ideas?

```
<form target="paypal_iframe" name="form_iframe" id="form_iframe" method="post" action="https://securepayments.paypal.com/cgi-bin/acquiringweb">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
<input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="100">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="my@email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">
<input type="hidden" name="template" value="templateD">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/receipt">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that could be causing it, is that if there are issues with the button and it being hosted or non hosted.

Comment: Thanks, how would I check this?

Comment: Can you provide the email address for your test sandbox seller account you are using, and I can try testing it to see what may be causing the issue.

Comment: For privacy/security I'd prefer not to post the email address publicly but the merchant ID is 3L9A5JW593BWQ which I think should work for you equally well.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution here was to add an extra field not covered in the iFrame documentation

```
<input type="hidden" name="showHostedThankyouPage" value="false">
```

Note that the field name is case sensitive.

PP_MTS_Chad was on the right line